# Android VideoView cannot load video when previous activity also has video

Tags: android, android-videoview

My app is for digital signage and has a screensaver that plays a fullscreen video after a timeout. When the timeout is triggered, the current activity is finished and the screensaver activity is started. The problem I'm having is that when the current activity contains an embedded video, the screensaver breaks with "Can't play this video".

There isn't really much code to show, I think it's a procedural problem. Do I need to do something to the VideoView to clear/release it besides simply finishing the containing activity?

The only relevant LogCat entry I can see seems to be `W/ResourceType(16285): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a03 (t=7 e=2563) in package 0 (error -75)`

Answer (score 1):

did you try to stop the video playback before finishing the activity ?

You can use :

`myVideoView.stopPlayback()`

Alos, I saw in other posts that Android usually displays this message, when it is not able to play the media content, for example : unsupported file format, unsupported codecs, erroneous content

Maybe you could try to play the same video as in your screensaver activity, to see whether it is a content problem

Also, you could check the video file path

Comment: I had it in onDestroy as well as onStop and neither made any change.

Comment: The problem could be somewhere else, I added new information

Comment: Valid points. I can confirm that the video format is correct as the screensaver has no problems from starting from other activities. It's only when finishing an activity with an embedded video is there a problem.

Comment: You may try to wait for a listener that would inform you the previuos playback is finished before to start another one